# fit through origin via matrix algebra

Tags: python

Usually I use the following code to carry out a linear fit or a quadratic fit. Sometimes it is necessary to weight the model 1/x2 using weight=2. I would like to know if I can force a model through the origin via adding some matrix algebra (obviously if weight=0). Thanks.

```
import numpy
from pylab import *
data=loadtxt('...')

degree=1
weight=0

x,y,w=data[:,0],data[:,1],1/data[:,0]**weight
n=len(data)
d=degree+1

f=zeros(n*d).reshape((n,d))
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,d):
        f[i,j]=x[i]**j

q=diag(w)
fT=dot(transpose(f),q)
fTx=dot(fT,f)
fTy=dot(fT,y)
coeffs=dot(inv(fTx),fTy)
```

Comment: There's no need for the nested for loops or pre-allocating `f`. Just do `f = numpy.power.outer(x, np.arange(d))`.  Equivalently, you could also do `f = x.reshape(-1,1)**np.arange(d)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `weight=0` case, get rid of the constant term in your feature vector by changing 
`for j in range(0,d)` to `for j in range(1,d)`.

For larger values of your `weight` term, the weights associated with `1/x^p` terms would have to be zero, which probably won't happen in the ordinary least squares solution.

For best numpy practices, I would suggest that you replace `zeros(n*d).reshape((n,d))` with `zeros( (n,d) )` and `dot(inv(fTx),fTy)` with `linalg.solve(fTx,fTy)`.

Comment: If `degree=1` and `weight=0`, I had already tried `for j in range(1,d)` but this gives a "LinAlgError: Singular matrix" about the `coeffs` calculation.

Comment: This is not a problem with the algorithm, but with your data. Add a small constant to the diagonal of fTx to improve stability.